# Edit rollback because I can't "put words in the author's mouth"

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I recently edited the accepted answer of my [question here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/308721/overwatch-competitive-points-reward-at-season-4-end) to provide [*additional information*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/308722/revisions) so that people with my same problem could find all the useful things in one single accepted post.

Later on, I got my edit rolled back by another user saying that he did that because I'm not supposed to put words in the author's mouth (in a rude way I would say, but that's another story).

I replied him back telling that I thought that edits were a way of improving answers, and, in my opinion, I was making life of future visitors easier. He replied once more saying that I was wrong and I should add a comment or a new answer.

I've been around at Stack Overflow for 2 and a half years and I never faced a situation like this. I'm pretty sure that I can make edits like that, but who knows, maybe I'm completely wrong. So I didn't edit back (I would have started an edit war) and decided to post here instead!

Comment: also, editing the **accepted answer** specifically because you want your opinion included in the "single accepted post" seems particularly inappropriate, even though you're the one who accepted it..

Comment: "Source: a friend of mine" that's not anywhere near enough justification for that edit.

Comment: Why is it on hold as off-topic? Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, edits are for improving answers. But improvements are not all equivalent. Edits are great when they:

- fix spelling, grammar, and punctuation
- fix typos or misformatting in code (but don't change someone's brace style to match your own)
- fix misuse of markdown (adding code ticks to inline keywords, remove excess bold and italics, make bulleted lists work properly)
- rearrange sentences so the answer is more coherent
- bring a linked image inline
- update a "dead" link to what you clearly know is the same resource at a different (working) address

Edits are not great when they:

- add another way to do the same thing
- add a parenthetical "but this won't work if xyz; in that case you need to abc"
- take away correct and relevant material simply because the editor disagrees with it

Imagine for example someone edited this answer and moved one of my bullets from one list to another. That's not cool.

You may want to look at the possible reasons for rejecting a suggested edit. They are usually pretty good reasons for rolling back an edit too.

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't get it why it's bad if i `add a parenthetical "but this won't work if xyz; in that case you need to abc"`. 

Let me explain: let's assume i edit your question to add and important element to your list, like a vital one, and it's not opinion based, it's like a defined rule.
 
People that comes after can easily find it there, in the accepted answer IF you agree with me and accept the edit. By the way, if that's the rule of the stackexchange community  (and it seems that everyone agrees with you) i'll just stick with it. 

Thank you all again for the kind answers.

Comment: Because it will look as though I made that point, and I didn't. Possibly even I wouldn't. The correct approach to someone simply forgetting something is to comment. The author usually says "thanks; edited" and then you can delete your comment and mission accomplished. Other times they don't.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer:** I'm not part of the *gaming* site.

I reviewed the answer, and the additional information you provided.

#### Executive summary

According to my intuition the additional information you provided doesn't seems to be part of the answer. A comment might be a good place to add those info.

#### Explanation

When you edit an answer, your edit should reflect the answer as the person who wrote it. You should make it clearer, that's all.

It is possible that the person who answered your question will disagree with the information you added.

On the other hand, adding a comment will put the information under your name, and it seems to me a good solution. Anyone will be able to distinguish between the original answer and your comment.

Comment: *Executive summary* Read that and banged my head on the desk five (5) times and punched three (3) babies.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, edits are used to improve the presentation of a post by things like: (1) correcting spelling or grammar, (2) adding a link that appears to have been omitted by mistake, or (3) some other way of improving presentation or formatting.

But if your intent is to improve it by adding information that was not there, you are now entering a domain where permission is needed. Community wiki posts are there for people who want their answers added to them. But this is not that. I would suggest that you talk to the person on chat to get permission to edit the answer, or supply the text there so he can edit it.